# touchstart, touchmove, touchend fire at the same time at tap up bug ios safari

Tags: ios, touchstart

I recently stumble on a bug in safari ios 13 but I think this happens in ios 12 as well.

I have registred on an element a touchstart, touchmove and touchend event but they all fire when I tap up the screen, it makes no sense.

Even if I register only touchstart still it is fireing when remove the finger from the screen, why is this happening?

Thank you.